# Keep the format of cells even after changing the values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have some conditional formatting, where the cell is colored if it has the "missing" text. Apparently, when I change the value of a cell form "missing" to anything else, formatting disappears.

How can I keep the formatting even if the values has been changed?

Comment: This is the whole point of conditional formatting I'm afraid. If you don't want to make use of this feature, simply delete the formatting rules and format your cells normally.

Comment: You could make a macro that is worksheet change and reacts to if cell "formatting" is missing and cell change and remove the conditional formatting and make a normal formatting as missing.

Comment: Another option would be to have VBA that will remove conditional formatting for a cell once it contains the text **"missing"**. Either way, I suspect you will need VBA to resolve this